Unserialize a Vue 3 Computed property
Is there a way to unserialize a computed property in Vue 3?
I have the class below:
  export default class Task {
    id: undefined
    pn: null
    quantity: null
    operation: null
    unit: null

    constructor(){
      Object.defineProperties(this, {
        $validations: {
          enumerable: false,
          writable: true,
        },
      })
    }

    protected $validations = computed(() => ({
      task_list_id: {
        required
      },
      pn: {
        required
      },
      quantity: {
        required
      },
      operation: {
        required
      },
    }))
}

That would be a DTO which would be sent to the API endpoint using Axios. It seems that enumerable: false doesn't work with computed properties, hence the $validations property is still being submitted on the request.

When using computed(callback) the property is a getter only. If you need a getter/setter use a writable computed: computed({ get() { return this.whatever }, set(val) { this.whatever = val })
